# Lightdm : Checking battery state - No login screen

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

I upgraded to oneiric Beta2 for some reasons I prevously explained. Now I cannot use LightDm. GDM works fine but cannot use Lightdm. When booting past Grub the message is checking battery state...[ok] and it checks forever.
Is there a work around?

I tried the command sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
which gave the result :

```
dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME missing
 dpkg-maintscript-helper: warning: environment variable DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE missing
```

Comment: Its a known bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/706354

Comment: This was not the problem. After reading the log in /var/logs/lightdm I found the problem is .Xauthority was in /var/lib/lightdm/ was owned by root. Deleting it and rebooting the machine did it! Happy with Lightdm!

Comment: While typing "checking battery state ubuntu 11.10" in google, it autocompletes this issue, yet somehow this was marked as too localized. PS- Happened to me 10 minutes ago. lets see if @Stefano solution can help.

Comment: so what happened with this too localized post of mine? @_@