# Upgrade process interrupted; can't boot and need to recover protected data

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade, sudo

I was using Ubuntu 11.04 and upgrading to 11.10. While the installation process was going on I shut it down. It can't come on again by itself. It will end up showing the status line "checking battery status".

The same problem is mentioned in [Crash after update to 11.10, from 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65988/crash-after-update-to-11-10-from-11-04) I have tried all my possibilities and all the commands I found in these discussion groups.

The next possible solution is to newly install the OS, but I need the data on my hard disk. As I have made them protected when opened with a LiveCD, there is an error saying "You do not have the permission to access them."

So I need to delete the administrator status through the terminal window. I can access my terminal window and run the `sudo` commands.

*So help me to delete the administrator status through the commands in the terminal window, please.*

Comment: When you say your data is "protected", do you mean you encrypted your home folder when you first installed Ubuntu (before upgrading)?

Answer (score 1):

While in the liveCD, run the command `gksu nautilus`. This should work as it opens nautilus as root. Alternatively, you can try to copy or move your files using the `sudo cp`or `sudo mv` respectively.

Although I **thoroughly** recommend to copy your data elsewhere, I'm also pretty sure that (if you have /home on a separate partition) you can reinstall Ubuntu without formatting /home.

Answer (score 0):

The error you just mentioned made me struggle for long, and solution is simple. Check this question:
[Lightdm : Checking battery state - No login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64759/lightdm-checking-battery-state-no-login-screen)

**EDIT**
I will quote it for you:

*This was not the problem. After reading the log in /var/logs/lightdm I found the problem is .Xauthority was in /var/lib/lightdm/ was owned by root. Deleting it and rebooting the machine did it! Happy with Lightdm!*

Comment: Dear Stefano, thank u for ur intetrest.
But really sorry. I can't catch what r u saying.
Can u say it some more simply....
Am not so familiar with ubuntu..
So pls help me and say in detail what should i do...

Comment: I had problem of my box failing to start and it ended at "checking battery status" and it will check forever. So I dug and come with solution (I don't remember where I got it) which was to delete.Xauthority file located in /var/lib/lightdm/