# boot stuck on "checking battery state [ok]"

Tags: installation, boot, battery

loaded ubuntu 12.10 but during boot gets stuck at `checking battery state  [ok]`. It appears its some kind of loop where this message keeps repeating. Any idea on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

[Some reported](https://askubuntu.com/q/64759/35775) it as corrupted `.Xauthority` file/ `.Xauthority` file owned by root. [Removing it does the trick](http://dbastreet.com/blog/?p=972).

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> when you are stuck.
2. Log in using your username and password.
3. Execute: `sudo mv /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority-bak`
4. Now reboot: `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed drivers before(downloaded from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) for your nvidia video card, just get a new version from that site and install it again.

It works for me.